# And statements in R when argument possibly empty

Tags: r, null

I want to make a single line conditional statement that checks whether a vector(X) has exactly one value, which is not missing. I had hoped that this would work:

```
(length(X) == 1) & !is.na(X)
```

But R evaluates both statements of an "AND" no matter what, so if X is NULL or has length zero, this will not work. The way I am currently performing this check is the VERY ugly

```
if (length(X) != 1) {FALSE}
else if (is.na(X)) {FALSE}
else {TRUE}
```

Comment: Use `&&` if you want to return a single TRUE FALSE also `is.na` would be applied to the whole vector, however `if/else` expects a single TRUE/FALSE input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `&&` instead of `&` will solve your problem.

```
x <- c()
(length(x) == 1) && !is.na(x)

[1] FALSE

x <- NULL
(length(x) == 1) && !is.na(x)

[1] FALSE
```